# How cut by contain in c#

Tags: c#

i want to get a matrix with equals contains: for example i have this entrance: [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6] the answer will be: [[1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4],[5,5],[6]]

```
int[] arr = [1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6]
int resCopy = []
int resTotal = []
int visited = []

for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {

            resCopy.push(arr[i])
            if(visited.indexOf(arr[i])==-1){
                visited.push(arr[i])

                    resTotal.Add(resCopy)
                    resCopy=[]

            }
        }
```

i think what need the similar reduce function same in javascript

other example:

```
1,2,2,2,1,1,3,4,5,5,6
first order 1,1,1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5,6
the answer [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4],[5,5],[6]]
```

EDIT:
  also the answer will be a dictionary

Dictionary[<1,[1,1]>,<2,[2,2,2]>,3<[3]>,<4,[4]>,<5,[5,5]>,<6,[6]>]

Comment: What happens if you have **1,1**,2,2,2,**1,1**,3,4,5,5,6? - Is the result `[[1, 1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3],[4],[5,5],[6]]`? Or `[[1,1],[2,2,2],[1,1],[3],[4],[5,5],[6]`?

Comment: @John first order please, i have edited my question

Comment: Then User965207's answer should do that for you except for perhaps the ordering :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use Linq to group the similar items as below

```
int[] arr = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6 };
  var arr1 = arr.GroupBy(s1 => s1).Select(s1 => s1.ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Comment: OP you can add `.OrderBy(s1 => s1)` before `.GroupBy` to ensure that numbers are in ascending order from 0.

Comment: the result will be an array of arrays containing same numbers

Comment: @User965207 a update please, how i can get a dictionary as well? i edited my question see please

Comment: var arr1 = arr.GroupBy(s1 => s1).Select(s1 => s1.ToArray()).ToDictionary(s=>s.First());  will generate a dictionary